# docker.py: why pass the volumes parameter twice?

Tags: python, docker

when creating docker containers using [docker.py](https://github.com/docker/docker-py), why do we need to pass the 'volumes' parameter twice ?

The [latest documentation](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/volumes/) says that:

> Volume declaration is done in two parts. Provide a list of
>   mountpoints to the Client().create_container() method, and declare
>   mappings in the host_config section.

If I'm creating a HostConfig object with 'create_host_config':

```
host_config = cli.create_host_config(
    binds=volumes,
)
```

And not passing a volume mapping to create_container:

```
result = cli.create_container(
    name='my_container', detach=True, image='my_image',
    host_config=host_config,
    command=['my', 'command']
)
```

It's working without any issue (so far).

So, what's the use of passing or not a volume mapping to the 'volumes' parameter to the 'create_container' method ?
Is it OK if I only pass this mapping to the 'binds' parameter of the 'create_host_config' ?

Thanks.